# Motorola Surfboard SBG6580 Parental Controls not found

Tags: cable-modem, parental-controls

I have a Motorola surfboard SBG6580.  I am trying to set up parental controls however I do not have it on the toolbar.  Every picture and guide I have looked at on the internet shows this option at the top. Why is it not there on mine?

Comment: Sounds like it was removed by your ISP which is tightly controlled, there are few options, and there is significant risk of bricking

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Yes; use a router connected to the modem

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the "firewall" tab. Then choose "web filter" on the sidebar. There you can set up access times and web site restrictions. Mine doesn't have parental controls either. I think it got renamed?

Notes:  i have to Input times adjusted for UTC. (not local time-and it has to change for daylight savings). Note allow or block option. Note the enable option (doesn't do anything if it isn't enabled). You might need to set up several filters to accomplish all of the controls you want, and make sure they work together.

It's generally functional, if a bit limited in scope.